# Inside vs. outside corners

Tags: word-request, nouns

I found this image:
[image]
in [this blog-post](http://blog.ashanging.com/2013/07/mount-click-rail-track-behind-crown-molding-during-a-room-make-over/).

There are two corners in the image: the leftmost is an "inside corner" and the rightmost is an "outside corner".

Are there single words (nouns) that can be used for "inside corner" and "outside corner"?

Comment: Or you could just simply call them _'inward'_ and _'outward'_ edges.

Comment: @VarunKN I would interpret inward and outward to be about the edge's position in space and not think of a concave or convex corner. An inward edge might be closer to the center of something than the outward edge.

Comment: I was just working on a building description and came across this concept that is missing a word. At first, injunctive corner seemed right for the concave configuration, as in "the subject's eastern injunctive corner", but exjunctive? It's fun to experiment with language, but if this goes to court, I would hate to look like a dumbass or cause injury to a client. For now I'm using convex and concave because at least they're demonstrable with diagrams (thank you to the last poster for that diagram).

Comment: [Related question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461867/term-for-wall-corner-facing-out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am thinking of a one-word noun for each and I couldn't think of anything. However, you might find this useful: [concave and convex (corners)](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/600/art%253A10.1186%252F2213-9621-1-1.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1186%2F2213-9621-1-1&token2=exp=1464166158~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F600%2Fart%25253A10.1186%25252F2213-9621-1-1.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Farticle%252F10.1186%252F2213-9621-1-1*~hmac=c7adcac89bf7d055c59077da31393748e70a0ad932fd7b23793ce086e866c613).This image is from the link:

[image]